# Social Media font awesome icon is not working in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-font-awesome

**ERROR**

> Attempted import error: 'faTwitter' is not exported from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'.

I'm using font awesome icons in react js there are few icons is working like:-
faPhoneAlt, faHeart, faBars, faChevronDown

but social media icons are not working.

**Code**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {faMapMarkerAlt, faPhoneAlt, faShoppingBag, faHeart, faBars, faChevronDown, faTwitter} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';


<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTwitter} /></Link>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why use close tag with </Link>  ?

Comment: This usually happens when you use an older version of the library. try to update to the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you need to install `free-brands-svg-icons`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons

In the doc it's clearly mentioned that for `brands` aka `social media`, you must to use another package.

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

Comment: I found this may be it helps [github issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/14047)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it's for `HTML` not for `react` because in `HTML` you need to use `fas` for solid and `fab` for solid brands